# apache2 mod_substitute with HTTP 403 Forbidden code

Tags: wordpress, apache2.4

Is there a way to use Apache2 mod_substitute for HTTP/1.1 403 Forbiden results ?

I'm using one Apache2 with mod_proxy, mod_substitute, etc as a load balancer for multiple PHP servers hosting a Wordpress installation. The returned content of the PHP servers contains links with internal hostnames. Those are replaced by mod_substitute to the external domain name. This setup is working fine for all results with a 200 status code.

But Wordpress sometimes uses 403 Forbidden. These pages for example contain "back"-links. The URLs in those pages are not replaced by my Substitute rules. The documentation of mod_substitute provides no information about this problem.

A proxy-side solution would be preferred. But I'm also thinking about changing the returned status codes by wordpress or writing my own apache2 mod.

Thanks

mod_substitute configuration within a <VirtualHost>

```
<Location />
    AddOutputFilterByType SUBSTITUTE text/html
    Substitute "s|http://backend.tld/|http://frontend.tld/|in"
</Location>
```

Comment: I don't see anything that limits it to successful responses. How did you add the filter?

Comment: I've added the mod_substitute configuration to the initial post.

Comment: My initial analysis was partially wrong: the problem exists only for 403 Forbidden, not for 302 Found. Changing the HTTP Codes in Wordpress therefore is possible but not desired. Other suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

A Wordpress-specific solution is adding the following code to a plugin:

```
function change_403_codes() {
    if(http_response_code () == 403) {
       http_response_code(200);
    }
}
add_action ('shutdown','change_403_codes');
```

Comment: This solution is not working with the new wp versions (>4.4).